# Convergence and power series relationship

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis class our professor said that as $z \to z_0$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k \left( z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}z_0+....+zz_0^{k-2}+(1-k) z_0^{k-1} \right) \to 0
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N} c_k \left( z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}z_0+....+zz_0^{k-2}+(1-k)z_0^{k-1} \right) \to 0
$$
as well.
I understood that bigger sum goes to zero since terms cancel out each other, however how can I deduce that partial sums also converge to zero? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to deduce it from the series? For each $k\in\Bbb Z_+$, you have$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}z_0+\cdots+zz_0^{\,k-2}+(1-k)z_0^{\,k-1}\right)=0,$$and therefore\begin{multline}\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{k=0}^Nc_k\left(z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}z_0+\cdots+zz_0^{\,k-2}+(1-k)z_0^{\,k-1}\right)=\\=\sum_{k=0}^N\lim_{z\to z_0}c_k\left(z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}z_0+\cdots+zz_0^{\,k-2}+(1-k)z_0^{\,k-1}\right)=0.\end{multline}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I get it now!